# SQL set LIMIT in WHERE IN

Tags: mysql

I Have table like this:

```
id   user_id   date
1    10        2018-12-13
3    11        2018-11-29
4    12        2018-12-05
```

My Query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE IN(10,11,12) AND date > 2018-11-15
```

Now I get all records fromt table > 2018-11-15 but I need to get first user records.

I get now:

```
id   user_id   date
1    10        2018-12-13
2    10        2018-12-01
3    11        2018-11-29
4    12        2018-12-05
5    12        2018-12-06
```

I need like this:

```
id   user_id   date
1    10        2018-12-13
3    11        2018-11-29
4    12        2018-12-05
```

Comment: Column name missing in Where condition.

Comment: I assume instead of `WHERE IN(10,11,12)` you meant `WHERE user_id IN(10,11,12)`

Comment: Are you join with any other tables?

Comment: So you want the highest date?

Comment: @Patrick For user 12 they have asked for 2018-12-05 which is the lowest date. For user 10 it's the highest date. The logic behind the desired output is not clear, IMO

Comment: Explain why `2018-12-05` appears as the `user_id = 12` record.  Why doesn't `2018-12-06` appear instead?

Comment: GROUP BY and MAX or MIN in SELECT could be used, but it depends on what line you want (highest date, lowest id)?

Comment: @Patrick You'll need some type of subquery (even if using `ROW_NUMBER`), because the OP wants to see all columns from the original table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you are right, assuming that he needs all the columns, this question needs answers. Where is OP in all this?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to join your table to a subquery which finds the latest records for each `user_id`:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.user_id,
    t1.date
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, MAX(date) AS max_date
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE user_id IN (10, 11, 12)
    GROUP BY user_id
) t2
    ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.date = t2.max_date
WHERE
    t1.user_id IN (10, 11, 12);
```

Comment: if it gets the max date for each user, then it won't return `2018-12-05` for user 12 as stated in the question. I can't personally see what the logic is for the list of returned dates, though

Comment: @ADyson I am assuming there is a typo in the OP's expected output.  It makes no sense to me to bother storing a date if the `id` column is what would determine the age of the record.

Comment: It rather looks like it's MIN(id) when you look at the output he wants

Comment: @Patrick Yes, I assumed that in my answer. Although, like TimBiegeleisen said *It makes no sense to me to bother storing a date if the id column is what would determine the age of the record*. However, I've seem many developer using the `id` for that purpose, perhaps because the think it is easier to compare integers than dates.

Answer (score 0):

To get the results in your question, you need to use grouping and find the minimum `id`:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.user_id, t1.date
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) AS min_id
            FROM table
            WHERE user_id IN(10, 11, 12)
              AND date > 2018-11-15
            GROUP BY user_id
           ) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.user_id IN (10, 11, 12)
  AND date > 2018-11-15;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a `NOT EXISTS` could be used for this.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable t1
WHERE user_id IN (10, 11, 12)
AND `date` > '2018-11-15'
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM yourtable t2
  WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id
    AND t2.id < t1.id
    AND t2.`date` > '2018-11-15'
);
```

Test on SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9060a8/1/0)